# Many-to-Many association throws "A is not associated to B" error

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a API where:

- Each user can have many songs.
- and each songs can have many likes (by users)

I'm new to Sequelize so i'm struggling with this issue. (keep in mind that the one-to-many association works, but many-to-many doesn't)

Here's my models and migrations:

models/user.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Song, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'songs',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
    User.belongsToMany(models.Song, {
      through: 'UserSongLike',
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      otherKey: 'songId',
      as: 'songsList',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

models/song.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Song = sequelize.define('Song', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Song.associate = function(models) {
    Song.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'songBy',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
    Song.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: 'UserSongLikes',
      foreignKey: 'songId',
      otherKey: 'userId',
      as: 'likedBy',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Song;
};
```

models/usersonglike.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserSongLike = sequelize.define('UserSongLike', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    songId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  UserSongLike.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return UserSongLike;
};
```

You can find the migrations here: https://gist.github.com/ExillustX/199b068912aae6368176718df13183e6

Now when i try to query the following code:

```
try {
  const query = await models.UserSongLike.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: models.User,
        as: "users",
        through: {
          model: models.UserSongLike,
          as: 'UserSongLikes',
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  console.log(query)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(er)
}
```

I get an error: **EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: User is not associated to UserSongLike!**

I'm not sure why this happens, could it be because i'm not adding table references in the migrations (or models)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate `User` and `Song`, the `UserSongLike` is an intermediate table that you don't need to declare here, the relation are created automatically by `sequelize`.

You can try something like this:

```
try {
  const query = await models.User.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Song,
      }
    ]
  });
  console.log(query)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(er)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, even tho i already figured out the issue before i saw your answer! Accepted anyway!

Comment: I have a question, do i need add attribute options (like references, allownull, validations, etc...) to both models and migration? Or is adding them in models enough?, sorry i'm not used to migrations!

Comment: The better to do is inform `attributes` options. If you have tables with a lot of columns, describing which columns do you want make the things faster due to sequelize parse only the columns that you have selected. Also, if you want only relate the table and don't need any column you can inform: `attributes: []` to avoid `SELECT *` on the table.